# What is the meaning of [] in a matlab function argument?

Tags: matlab

I found the following function call:

```
reshape(A, 1, [])
```

This flattens matrix A colum major. I am trying to understand the call. The function documentation says after A there should be a size vector for the reshaped matrix, but in here there is a one followed by [] instead of a two-vector. Is this a way of saying "Do whatever it takes so the matrix will have one row, I don't care what the width is"?

How come Matlab lets you exchange one argument for two like this? I tried googling around and did not find an explanation, and I want to understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[]` is an empty matrix. In many MATLAB built-in functions, an empty matrix is interpreted to mean "use the default argument here" or "automatically determine this value". Occasionally it is used to disambiguate two meanings of a function, as with the `max` function, where `max(A,2)` compares each element of `A` to 2 and returns the larger, while `max(A,[],2)` finds the largest element of each row.

If you read the [help for `reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html?refresh=true), you will see the following:

> You can specify a single dimension size of `[]` to have the dimension size automatically calculated, such that the number of elements in `B` matches the number of elements in `A`. For example, if `A` is a 10-by-10 matrix, then `reshape(A,2,2,[])` reshapes the 100 elements of `A` into a 2-by-2-by-25 array.

Comment: Thank you, must've missed it there.